# Trigger Gallery slider from outside by thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have gallery slider work with thumbnail images.

And i need to open images of slider from outside of slider, by links. So i tried with this code.

But when i click out side links, it always open first slide image only.

```
$(window).click(function(){
  var target="#1";  
  $('a[href='+target+']').click()
})
```

when i click 1st thumb it trigger #1, but when i click 2nd, 3rd 4th... thumb it trigger again same #1. but i need when i click 2nd thumb , it must open #2....

i use this code for out side thumbnails. whats wrong with this code.

```
    <div class="main">
                    <a href="#1"><img src="images/thumbs/c1.jpg" data-largesrc="images/large/c1.jpg" alt="image01"/></a>
                    <a href="#2"><img src="images/thumbs/c2.jpg" data-largesrc="images/large/c2.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
                    <a href="#3"><img src="images/thumbs/c3.jpg" data-largesrc="images/large/c3.jpg" alt="image03"/></a>
</div>
```

this slider is working perfectly. but i need to click this thumbnails from out side of the slider, to trigger each image of the slider.

```
<ul class="thumb">
   <li><img src="images/thumbs/c1.jpg"  /></li>
   <li><img src="images/thumbs/c2.jpg"  /></li>
   <li><img src="images/thumbs/c3.jpg"  /></li>
</ul>
```

When i click .thumb, target must be main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger any event manually you need to use trigger() method. Try below.

```
$('body').on("click",".thumb li", function(){
    var target= $(this).attr("data-ref");  // target will give you #1 or #2 or #3
    $('.main a[href='+target+']').trigger('click');

});

<ul class="thumb">
   <li data-ref="#1"><img src="images/thumbs/c1.jpg"  /></li>
   <li data-ref="#2"><img src="images/thumbs/c2.jpg"  /></li>
   <li data-ref="#3"><img src="images/thumbs/c3.jpg"  /></li>
</ul>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrDcS/)

Comment: this code also open same image of the slider. only first image.

Comment: i have out side link for each images of the slider. when i click first link, it must #1. when i click second link, it must #2. when i click third link, it must #3.

Comment: Also I doubt what this `$('a[href='+target+']').click()` does  in your code?

Comment: My first code is open first image for all outside links. but these codes are not open any images.

Comment: When i click .thumb, target must be .main.

Comment: can u tell me how to change this code for click inside  links of .main to trigger outside thumbs.

Comment: that will lead to infinite click loop.. Say clicking on an item in .main you are triggering the click event of corresponding item in .thumb. Since you have added a click listener to this item to trigger the click event of corresponding item in .main it will trigger click of the item in .main again... this will be a loop which will not end :)

Comment: but when i click out side it works. but when i click in side it's not trigger out side links. i need trigger both inside and out side links, by clicking both inside and outside links.